# c# Automapper - How to map object in objetc

Tags: c#, automapper

I want to mapper these two object,

```
public class Update
{        
    public string aa{ get; set; }               
}

public class Date
{
    public DateTime ww{ get; set; }        
}

 public class Update11
{
    public string aa{ get; set; }        
}

public class Date
{
    public DateTime ww{ get; set; }        
}
```

I createMap:
CreateMap<Update, Update11>();
CreateMap<Update11, Update>();

Comment: Add configuration also for types `DateRange`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your `DateRange` models to your mapper profile.

```
CreateMap<namespace1.DateRange, namespace2.DateRange>().ReverseMap();
```

Depending on which version you are using you can also use `.ReverseMap()` instead of explicitly creating a map for the reverse mapping.

```
CreateMap<UpdateCost11, UpdateCostDto>().ReverseMap();
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though the classes DateRange on Dto and your main class have the same structure, their namespace is different. And auto-mapper won't map it as you want it.

You either have to delete one of the DateRange classes and go with one of them or as @Hamlet Hakobyan suggested, you have to add the following configuration

```
CreateMap<SourceNameSpace.DateRange, DestinationNameSpace.DateRange>();
```

> Change SourceNameSpace and DestinationNameSpace to the one you have.